# getResource from the current thread is returning FileNotFoundException but the file exists at the location

Tags: jboss, filenotfoundexception

Looking at questions like this one: [How to get Runtime Web Application path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389879/how-to-get-runtime-web-application-path)

let me to eventually go with this code to get the file name:

`String fileName = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("./myfile.yml").getFile();`

This code gets compiled into a war file for uploading into JBOSS EAP 6.2, and the file gets copied into the /WEB-INF/classes folder of the war file. I can verify this by exploding the war myself and seeing it.

When I run the above code, however, I get a FileNotFoundException and the path it points to is the {pathto exploded war}/WEB-INF/classes/myfile.yml

Any ideas?